# need help joining tables in sql

Tags: mysql

i cant get around this question in my assesment,need a little help,

q)What are the BookingIDs and check in and out dates for bookings for Michelle Bonnier?
using the global holidays database.

A)

```
select bookingid,guestid,firstname,lastname,checkindate,checkoutdate
from guests
join bookings on guests.GuestID = bookings.GuestID
where firstname = "Michelle"
and lastname = "Bonnier";
```

Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'guests'

Comment: At minimum you need to alias the columns that are not unique, in this case, at least the `guestid` field.  `select bookingid, guests.guestid, ...`

Comment: Can you give create statements for the tables, so We can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As guestid is in both tables in the select column list we need to say that which one to use, So try this:

```
SELECT bookingid,
       guests.guestid,
       firstname,
       lastname,
       checkindate,
       checkoutdate
FROM   guests
       JOIN bookings
         ON guests.guestid = bookings.guestid
WHERE  firstname = "michelle"
       AND lastname = "bonnier"
```

Answer (score 1):

Always try to use table name alias

```
select 
    b.bookingid,g.guestid,g.firstname,g.lastname,
    b.checkindate,b.checkoutdate
    from guests g
    join bookings b on g.GuestID = b.GuestID
    where g.firstname = "Michelle"
    and g.lastname = "Bonnier";
```